# How do i mock httpresponse.clear() with MOQ framework for unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, .net-7.0, xunit.net

I cannot find any good answer for this and if it exists, remove this question.
I wanna mock for httpresponse.clear() with moq framework but do not know how to do?

This is the package:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.responseextensions.clear?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```
var mockHttpResponse = new Mock<HttpResponse>();    
mockHttpResponse.Setup(x => x.Clear());
```

and also

```
mockHttpResponse.SetupGet(x => x.Clear());
```

But it throws `Not supported` when running tests.

Comment: `Clear()` seems to be an extension methods, which are always static and thus cannot be mocked with Moq.

Comment: One solution *could* be to look at the implementation of `Clear()`, see which methods it calls and try to create `Setup()`s for those methods instead.

Comment: why do you want to mock the response in the first place, and not your service?

Comment: Indeed, why mock Clear, or even use Clear? In both controller-based and minimal APIs the response is constructed from your action's result. This sounds like an attempt to migrate WebForms code to .NET 7, where `Clear` was needed eg in file downloads, to remove any headers already emitted by controls or event handlers.

Comment: What are you trying to test? [ControllerBase.Response](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L48) returns `HttpContext?.Response`. In ASP.NET Core you can inject your own test HttpContext instance to a controller. You don't need to mock the Response's methods because you already have a fully functional instance.